# How to Check conditions line by line and how to disable single lines temporarily?

Tags: c#, if-statement, nested

```
enum Condition
{
    Off,
    On,
    Other
}

Condition val1, val2, val3;

bool CheckCondition()
{
    if (!(val1 == Condition.On)) return false;
    if (!(val2 == Condition.Off)) return false;
    if (!(val3 == Condition.On)) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Result should be: if(val1 && val2) return true;

Problem: if e.g. val2 == Condition.Off it should be ignored temporary, until it is set again to Condition.On, but all other verifications should be computet line by line !

Only if all remaining verifications are true the function should return true state.

If a condition is Off the whole function should NOT return false because of that. Instead all other checks should be made and if all the ramaining checks are true, function should return true (without considering e.g. val2 in the example above during this check).

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

Just return full condition. Like below, You can performe `OR` check.

Below condition will return true when any or all val are set to `Condition.On`, It will return false only when all are set to `Condition.Off`.

```
enum Condition
{
    Off,
    On
}

Condition val1, val2, val3;

bool CheckCondition()
{
    return (val1 == Condition.On) || (val2 == Condition.On) || (val3 == Condition.On);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, because e.g. if val2 is Off, I need CheckCondition only return true, if val1 && val 2 are both true. In your example it will return true if val1 OR val3 is true. The remaining conditions are operated with AND operator.

Comment: Can you add scenario in wich your function should return true and false?

Comment: If val 1 in On and Val 3 is On and val 2 if Off it should return true. If val 1 is neither On or Off and Val 3 is On and val 2 if Off it should return false.

Comment: It is a row of AND connected boolean variables where the number of variables that should be considered varies depending on the fact if they are set to Off or not.

Comment: Hey, just a suggestion! It would be helpful if you could sketch out a truth table and based on the output, try to combine the clauses to get your conditions. You can post the truth table in the question as well for better responses.

Comment: It is just as follows: bool CheckCondition()
{
    return (val1 == Condition.On) && (val2 == Condition.On) && (val3 == Condition.On);
}, whereas it should be optional which values are &&-connected.